# all the fields are not showing to already existing customers on edit page in nested form on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following railcast nested form

for example: I have 4 fields on signup page and 12 fields on edit page(actually, I needed more basic information)

when new customers register they are getting all 12 fields to fill up on edit page and all the things working good.

but, when old customers login(already registered before nested form creation) they are not getting all fields now, just getting 4 fields

I am using something like this:

## Controller

```
 def new

    @user = User.new
    @user.build_user_nickname_live
    @user.build_user_twitter_chipcount
    @user.user_twitter_reals.build
    @user.user_twitter_fakes.build
end

def edit

     @user = User.find(current_user.id)

  end
```

## model

```
has_one :user_nickname_live

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_nickname_live

has_one :user_twitter_chipcount

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_chipcount

has_many :user_twitter_reals, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_reals,
   :allow_destroy => true

has_many :user_twitter_fakes, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_fakes,
   :allow_destroy => true
```

## view

```
<%= nested_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
                    :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

    <div style="overflow: hidden;display: block;">
      <%= f.fields_for :user_nickname_live do |user_nickname_live| %>
          <!--span 2 and 4 with min-padding-->
          <div class="span2 min-padding">
            <label >Live Nickname</label>
          </div>
          <div class="span4 min-padding">
            <div class="input-control text">
              <%= user_nickname_live.text_field :nickname,:style=>"max-width: 253px;", :placeholder=>"Live nickname",:onchange=>"changeInfo();" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--ends-->
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;display: block">
      <%= f.fields_for :user_twitter_chipcount do |user_twitter_chipcount| %>
          <!--span 2 and 4 with min-padding-->
          <div class="span2 min-padding">
            <label >Chip count account</label>
          </div>
          <div class="span4 min-padding">
            <div class="input-control text">
              <%= user_twitter_chipcount.text_field :twitter_url,:style=>" max-width: 250px;", :id=>"twitter_url", :placeholder=>"Chip count account" ,:onchange=>"changeInfo();" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--ends-->
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div id="real-one" style="display:block;position: relative;">
      <div class="add-click">
        <%= f.link_to_add "", :user_twitter_reals, :class=>"icon-plus",:style=>"font-size: 14px;", :data => { :target => "#real-field" } %>
      </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :user_twitter_reals do |real_one| %>
          <div id="real-field"  style="overflow: hidden;">
            <!--span 2 and 4 with min-padding-->
            <div class="span2 min-padding">
              <label >Real</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 min-padding">
              <div class="input-control text" >
                <%= real_one.text_field :twitter_url,:style=>"max-width: 250px;",:placeholder=>"Real",:onchange=>"changeInfo();" %>
                <%= real_one.link_to_remove "", :class=>"icon-minus minus-click" %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--ends-->

          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div id="twitter-fake" style="display: block;position: relative;">
      <div class="add-click">
        <%= f.link_to_add "", :user_twitter_fakes, :class=>"icon-plus",:style=>"font-size: 14px;", :data => { :target => "#fake-field" } %>
      </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :user_twitter_fakes  do |user_twitter_fake| %>

          <div id="fake-field"  style="overflow: hidden;">
            <!--span 2 and 4 with min-padding-->
            <div class="span2 min-padding">
              <label >Fake</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 min-padding">
              <div class="input-control text">
                <%= user_twitter_fake.text_field :twitter_url,:style=>"max-width: 250px;",:placeholder=>"Fake",:onchange=>"changeInfo();" %>
                <%= user_twitter_fake.link_to_remove "", :class=>"icon-minus minus-click" %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--ends-->
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Help me please.

Comment: Format your code properly!

Comment: okay formatted the code above

Comment: No you didn't, what about model and controller?

Comment: "when old customers register(already registered before" that's the strangest sentence I ever seen on SO.

Comment: Hello  Michael Szyndel , I am sorry for my English, actually  I already have some old customers login details in my account. when I use those information I don't see all fields on edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time your old users where created these associations didn't exist.

So if an old user now wants to edit its profile stuff like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_nickname_live do |user_nickname_live| %>
```

can't disply anything because the association hasn't been built in your DB.

You could create a migration, or a rake task, or a background task or fix it in irb to addthe associations for the old users users

I didn't tried it, but it should work.
create a migration call it e.g: build_user_nickname_live_associations and put inside:

```
def up
  users = User.find(:all)

  users.each do |u|
    unless u.nick_name_live.present?
      u.build_nick_name_live
      u.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hello Flo, you are almost right, i am building all the associations on new function but I want to show the field on edit page. is there any way to build association on edit page without duplication???

Comment: you can give the method: find_or_initialize_by_ a try. Or write a short script/rake/migration to build asscociations where none exists.

Comment: hello Flo, actually I am new in this language can you please give me suitable example how to do that???

Comment: Hey Flo, i have atleast 2 lakh existing data in my user table so my system is hanged up

Comment: sorry i don't understand your comment. what means lakh and what do you mean with your system hanged up?

Comment: I am sorry Flo.  I mean i have 2 lakhs = 0.2 Millions existing data in my user table and when i execute rake db:migrate command, it starts endless loop in command prompt.

Comment: ah ok, good to know :) i think your system doesn't hung up, it just takes a long time so save ~ 0,2Mio datasets. I hope you are doing this on a dev server ;) you can test if it works for only one user where you know its id like: user = User.find_by_id(the id you know here) and than run: user.build_nick_name_live and save it with user.save than reload irb and see if it worked

Comment: hey I changed  users = User.find(:all) to users = User.find(current_user)

and it starts working.
Thanks for your help Flo.